# Why should boostrap sample size equal the original sample size?

Tags: sample-size, bootstrap

When searching the internet on the sample size of for boostrap samples I generally find that the size should equal the original sample size. However, I can't find any explanation on why this should be the case.

- In what way is it bad to use a smaller sample size?
- Is it always better to use a larger sample size?

Some of the sites which report this:
http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/bootstrapped-samples-guidelines/
http://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall12/sta101.002/Sec3-34.pdf

Comment: Those sites also contain the answer to your question. Can you clarify why you are not satisfied with those answers?

Comment: @MaartenBuis The links only say we should do it with the original sample size, but didn't explain or give a proof.

Comment: At heart you're trying to infer something about the behaviour of some aspect of the sampling distribution of some statistic of interest (e.g. a standard error) *at the sample size you have*.

Comment: Quoted from your first link: " However, the standard error estimates are dependent upon the number of observations in each replication. Here, on average, we would expect the variance estimate of _b[foreign] to be twice as large for a sample of 37 observations than that for 74 observations. This is due mainly to the form of the variance of the sample mean, s2/n."

Answer (score 18):

This is from Efron and Tibshirani's *An Introduction to the Bootstrap* (first sentence of Chapter 2):

> The bootstrap is a computer-based method for assigning measures of
>   accuracy to statistical estimates.

This suggests that we should in some way respect the correct sample size $n$: **The accuracy of statistical estimates depends on the sample size**, and your statistical estimate will come from a sample of size $n$.

---

### How to estimate the standard error of the mean with the bootstrap, and how you're fooling yourself if you draw bootstrap samples of any other size than $n$.

We understand the behavior of the mean very well. As you'll no doubt remember from intro to stats, the standard error of the mean depends on the sample size, $n$, in the following manner: $SEM = s/\sqrt{n}$, where $s^2$ is the sample variance.

The *bootstrap principle* is that a bootstrap sample relates to your sample as your sample relates to the population. In other words you're assuming your sample is a pretty good approximation to the population and that you can use it as a proxy. Let $x^{*b}$ denote the $b$-th bootstrap sample, and let $\hat \mu^*_b$ be the mean of this bootstrap sample. The bootstrap estimate of standard error is:

$$
SE_\mathrm{boot} = 
\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{b=1}^B (\hat \mu^*_b - \bar \mu^*)^2}{(B-1)}}
$$
where $B$ is the number of bootstrap samples you've drawn (the more the merrier,) and $\bar \mu^* =  \sum \hat \mu^*_b/B$ is the average of the bootstrapped means. This is a long way of saying that **the bootstrap estimate of standard error is simply the sample standard deviation of the bootstrapped statistics**. You're using the spread in the bootstrapped means to say something about the accuracy of the sample mean.

Now, we're bootstrapping, so we're treating the original sample as a population: it is a discrete distribution with mass $1/n$ at each data point $x_i$. We can draw as many samples from this as we want, and in principle we can make them as large or small as we want. If we draw an $n^*$-sized bootstrap sample and estimate its mean $\hat \mu^*$, we know that $\hat \mu^* \sim N(\hat \mu, s/\sqrt{n^*})$. **For $n^*=n$ the standard deviation of your bootstrapped mean is exactly the central limit theorem-dictated $SEM$ for the original sample. This isn't true for any other $n^*$.**

So in this example, if $n^* = n$, the sample standard deviation of $\{\hat \mu^*_b\}$ is a good representation of the correct standard error of the mean. If you draw larger bootstrap samples you get really good estimates of the sample mean, but **their spread no longer directly relates to the standard error you're trying to estimate** because you can make their distribution arbitrarily tight.

Comment: For other problems where the bootstrap doesn't work well modifications like m out of n work.

Comment: Note that this is basically the same answer as in the https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268024/the-bootstrap-distribution-and-the-number-of-resamples which I was not aware of when writing this